# JQuery post request with Express error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

I am making the following request in the front-end with jquery:

```
  try {
    await $.post("/test", data, () => {
      console.log("received");
    })
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error.status);
  }
```

The request is received by a back-end Express router:

```
app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test received")
  res.status(400).send("Error message");
})
```

The back-end sends an error message of the status 400. Although the error is getting caught by the `catch` statement in the front-end, and the error is being displayed, the browser console still displays the red error of `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).`

I am wondering if as a best practice, it is ok to have that error message to show up on the browser? I thought about it, and don't see any issue that the error would cause. Furthermore, what would be some of the best practices to handle error return by front-end jQuery/HTTP requests.

Comment: if the request is an error, the console will present it. that's normal.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that it is not possible to not show that error in the console?

Comment: Well, no, you could just not let it error in the first place. But if an http error occurs, it will display

Comment: ok, that was I was wondering. If the error occurs, there is no way to not let it fall into the console.